# Migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Developers Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, migration, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've done some reading on the installation but it's not clear to me whether I will be UPGRADED to the SQL Server Developers edition or whether the install will create another instance. I want to get rid of SQL Server Express. Will the install give me that option?

If the install does not provide that option

- What files must be deleted?
- Are there any configuration items I need to gather before the install?
- Anything else to be aware of?

Comment: Step 1: **uninstall** SQL Server Express - step 2: **install** SQL Server Developer edition. Don't start to meddle around your system yourself, manually deleting stuff - use the proper uninstall / install steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can install a separate instance.
Don't even try to delete or replace sql server files manually - use standard windows instrumentation instead - uninstall it as regular application.
As far as I know - there were no any options to upgrade from express edt. to developer, if you need so - just keep your db in safe place, uninstall express, install developer, attach the db. And be aware of developer license restrictions!